# Regularization vs. Validation

Tags: validation, regularized

What I always see in the papers and articles about under/overfitting is a falling curve for training error and a U-shaped curve for testing error, saying the area left to the U-curve bottom is subject to underfitting and the area right to it is subject to overfitting.
To find the best model, we can test each configuration (e.g. changing the number of nodes and layers) and compare the test error values to find the minimum point (typically via cross-validation). That  looks straightforward and perfect.

Do we need a regularizer to achieve this point? This is what I am not sure I have the topic understood well. To me, it seems that we don't need a regularizer if we can test different model configurations. The only case when a regularizer comes to play is when we have a fixed model configuration (e.g. fixed number of nodes and layers) and don't want to try other configurations, so we use regularizer to limit the model complexity by forcing other model parameters (e.g. network weights) to low values. Is this view right?

But if it is right, then what is the intuition behind it? First of all, when using a regularizer we don't know in advance if this network configuration/complexity bring us to the right or left of the minimum of test error curve. It may be already underfit, overfit, or fit. Putting math aside, why forcing weights to lower values will cause network to be more generalizable and less overfit? Is there any analogy of this method with the previous method of moving along test loss curve to find its minimum? Also regularizer does its job while training, it can not do anything with test data. How can it help to move toward minimum test error?